# PowerShell command to list what files are opened by active applications

Tags: python, powershell

I wish to print the paths of all opened files in active applications. By opened files I mean those opened by the user, not files opened in the background. By active applications I mean those with windows. For example, if Word is opened I would like to print the path of the document that is open in word. Ultimately, I will be using Python but a PowerShell command solution is what I want as I will be invoking PowerShell through Python.

Currently I am using the code below to print a list of active applications:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | select Description,Id,Path,Name'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if not line.decode()[0].isspace():
        print(line.decode().rstrip())
```

How can I get a list of the files opened by these applications?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this help you? https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2019/07/how-to-check-what-files-are-in-use-on-a-remote-windows-computer/

Comment: A bit. I have used Handle to get all of the opened files but now how do I filter these handles to get only the ones opened by the user. eg the handle of a .pdf  document opened in adobe and not all the background files. Thanks!